# Django - Is it possible to override the name of a field from a model in a ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
class UserForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    given_name = forms.CharField(column_name='first_name')
    surname = forms.CharField(column_name='last_name')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

So any data passed to `given_name` and `surname` get stored to `first_name` and `last_name` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is override field attributes, then you don't need to define new fields, just override the ones you already have, as you need.

```
class UserForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms... # override as per your needs
    last_name = forms...

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

BUT, if for some reason you need renamed fields, then override the form's `save()` method and assign the values to corresponding model fields before save. In this case, you can also remove `first_name` and `last_name` from `fields`.

```
fields = ['username', 'email',]

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
    your_model = super(YourForm, self).save(commit=False)
    your_model.first_name = self.cleaned_data['given_name']
    your_model.last_name = self.cleaned_data['surname']

    if commit:
        your_model.save()
```

Comment: Do I no longer need to include `given_name` and `surname` in the `fields` list?

Comment: Does you model have `given_name` and `surname` fields? If yes, then you can add them. `fields` is the list of model's fields that you want to show in the form. From your example, I assumed your model only have `first_name` and `last_name`.